# Calculating stocks' returns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with multiple stocks' price across days:

```
   Date Stock_Name Price
1 10-01          A   100
2 10-01          B     5
3 10-01          C     2
4 10-02          A   110
5 10-02          B    10
6 10-02          C     3
7 10-03          A   121
8 10-03          B    20
9 10-03          C     6
```

Now, I want to group by each stock based on their names, and calculate their daily return from 10-01 to 10-03, ideally:

```
   Date Stock_Name Price Return
1 10-01          A   100     NA
2 10-01          B     5     NA 
3 10-01          C     2     NA
4 10-02          A   110    0.1
5 10-02          B    10      1
6 10-02          C     3    0.5
7 10-03          A   121    0.1
8 10-03          B    20      1
9 10-03          C     6      1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you post the data in reproducible format you'll get answers more quickly!

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Stock_Name) %>% mutate(daily_return = round(Price/lag(Price) - 1,digits = 1))` with `df` your data. Plus, don't call your new variable Return: it is, on capital R close, a function name.

Comment: @MonJeanJean and others, also don't call your data.frame `df`, `df` is also a function in base R, namely the density function of the F distribution. :-)

Comment: @phiver Ho, didn't know, thanks!

Comment: It's common practice on SO to call dataframes `df` and it's common practice to post complete solutions in answers not in comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` to do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, return := (Price / shift(Price) ) -1 , by=Stock_Name]
dat
```